# PDF: how do I find how much space will the text occupy when rendered?

Tags: c, pdf

I am writing a little PDF library in C. When generating PDF source code that is responsible for rendering text, I need to know how much space the rendered text occupies in order to render the next paragraph correctly.

How do I find out?

Thank you!

Comment: That's pretty well explained in the specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) chapter 9. Essentially you need to know the current graphic state (which should be easy because you after all create the PDF) and the metrics of the font you use and then calculate.

Comment: @mkl, could you please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mechanisms and math of PDF text rendering are exhaustively explained in the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). Most important are chapters 8 *Graphics* and 9 *Text.*

Essentially you need to know the current graphic state (which should be easy because you after all are the one who creates the PDF) and the metrics of the font you use and then calculate.

Most of these details are governed by the operators and calculations described in chapter 9 but one should not forget the current transformation matrix described in chapter 8.