# Measuring string size in plain C

Tags: c, pdf, graphics, fonts

Imagine you are generating a PDF program "by hand" (no libraries) from within a C program you are developing. You want to write a function that subscripts arbitrary text. The best thing to imagine here is how TeX subscripts the `\inf` and `\sup` symbols when typesetting math.

Now, when you add a subscript to the `\inf` symbol, nothing interesting happens, it just sits there. On the other hand, adding subscript to the `\sup` symbol causes the subscripted text to move a few units downwards because of the letter "p" whose descent is a little below the baseline of the font.

My question then is, what is the best way to read glyph metrics from a Type-1 or OTF font so that typesetting can be done perfectly? I am looking especially for the *ascent*, *descent* and *width* metrics as they are referred to in th PDF format specification.

---

As parsing font files looks like "doing work instead of the PostScript interpreter", which has to perform those calculations to lay down individual letters that eventually constitute words and paragraphs, it would be nice if I could refer to the "end of the last text string" in the PDF PostScript stream.

Consider this fragment of PDF PostScript stream: `BT /F1 12 Tf 0 0 Td (Hello World!)Tj (Hello again!)Tj ET`, "Hello again" renders **precisely where it should be**. So the PostScript interpreter knows (of course) where the next batch of text written with `Tj` should begin, but I do not know how to refference this information so that I can avoid all the messy font parsing.

---

**If anyone runs into this trouble, have a look at [a similar question I posted on Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1265469), I got some valuable information there as well.**

Comment: is `sizeof()?` what you are looking for?

Comment: I didn't get the *font* thing you are talking about

Comment: I guess he's talking about the physical dimensions of a string when rendered (e.g. on screen), in which case we would need to know what environment this is for (i.e. what OS/GUI/etc).

Comment: Sorry, I should have made myself clear. I am generating a PDF file and need to know the *exact* size of the individual glyphs given a font (either Type-1 or OTF), so that I can achieve higher type-setting quality.

Comment: Can you improve the question @David ?

Comment: @PaulR Yes, that is it. I would like it to be platform-independent.

Comment: Do you anyway use any API for setting the Text into your TextBox? Like, in emWin, you can set the Size of the Textbox and, you can obviously set the Text into that Textbox, considering its size (which is dependent on the font that you select)..

Comment: @David: How is this different from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911778/pdf-how-do-i-find-how-much-space-will-the-text-occupy-when-rendered? - You have to read the font metrics and calculate ...

Comment: Not really, I am generating the whole PDF by hand. I only have basic PostScript commands available.

Comment: Dear David, welcome to stackoverflow. Judging by the number of comments it seems that your question can be improved by stating more clearly what it is you are using, what you have tried, and what has failed. This will be appreciated by the people trying to help you and will likely improve your chance of a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the font file you have to read the font metrics, the width of each glyph (GW). These widths are given in a 1000 unit grid. You compute the actual width of a glyph at a given font size using this formula: pageGlyphWidth = fontSize * GW / 1000;
Then you scale the computed value with the current transformation matrix.

Comment: This is what I am looking for! Do these metrics have to be parsed from the various font formats?

Comment: Yes, you have to write your parser for each font format you want to support and extract the metrics from the font file.

Comment: Okay, let's face the truth. One more question, if you do not mind: is it possible to extract *ascent*, *descent* and *width* and *height* metrics of individual glyphs in a reasonable way? (Reasonable: parse the information out, they are contained within the file. Not reasonable: calculating the Bezier curves and then looking for extrema points.)

Comment: @David that looks like an interesting question in its own right.

Comment: @David yes, all this information (ascent, descent) is available directly in the font file as part of some font defined structures.

Comment: @iPDFdev, thank you! I will look into it and in case I run into trouble, I will open a thread with this specific topic.

Comment: ascent and descent: not per character. width, yes; height, no. If you are just getting started, don't attempt to try and parse every font format there is. Find yourself a few Type 1 fonts, and only parse the AFM file that comes with it. That's enough for a pretty decent basic layout engine.

Comment: @Jongware, thank you. I have been instructed to look into AMF on Adobe forums, too. In your experience, is the usage of the AMF files encouraged/common/expected, or rather a last chance to avoid font parsing?

Comment: @David There are some tools which allow you to extract AFM files from many fonts without AFM companion. Thus, without any loss of generality, you can assume that there are AFM files.

Comment: @David: AFM is an easy-to-parse plain text format, so you can quickly concentrate on the more important aspects of your code. Correctly reading character metrics out of *any* (or even *one* type of) font file is far from trivial, and perhaps best circumvented by using a comprehensive library such as [FreeType](http://www.freetype.org/). By the way, manually creating PDFs is a great way to learn coding, *and* the PDF file format, *and* basic typography.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer as it pointed me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

*[This text was written as the answer to the original question:*

> *How do I measure string size when rendered to a PDF using plain C given only the font file, the string and the font size? Is there a way?*

*It does not really match the updated question.]*

The mechanisms and math of PDF text rendering are exhaustively explained in the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf). Most important are chapters 8 *Graphics* and 9 *Text.* Section 9.4.4 aggregates the information and calculations concerning the horizontal and vertical displacement between two characters drawn in sequence

[image: section 9.4.4 "Text Space Details" from ISO 32000-1]

While this looks a bit complicated, it very likely reduces to trivial math in your case as you say you are *generating the whole PDF by hand* and, therefore, most likely have trivial values for the variables involved.

Unfortunately you did not provide your hand-generated PDF; otherwise you could be told in more detail to what the equations can be reduced in your case.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. Unfortunately, I seem to fail to make myself clear when describing what the problem is. I am reading the Adobe PDF spec for two days now and I have not yet found the answer to my question. The math behind keeping track of the text state is not causing the problem; the problem is how to get extensive font information for the individual glyphs, especially ascent and descent. As I am trying to avoid parsing font files, I am asking whether this can be done in pure PostScript, like referring (somehow) to the location where the previous text batch ended.

Comment: One more thing; thank you for your answer on the previous post. You answered what I had been asking for, but it seems I did not ask it the right way.

Comment: I'm afraid *get extensive font information for the individual glyphs* and *avoid parsing font files* contradict each other here. The PDF in PDF syntax only has very basic font information (as much as required for a dumb PDF viewer to render the PDF). Everything else has to be searched in the font, e.g. individual *ascent and descent* values.

Comment: I see. That is precisely what I was not sure about; the amount of information other than the font program itself that is carried inside the PDF about the font. So the `/Widths` array is there just to support basic rendering/lend a helping hand to "dumb readers"? Nothing else?

Comment: @David The **Width** array says: "After drawing the character at position p, advance this far for drawing the next character." (And this value has to be adapted as described by the formulas above.) It does not say anything about the glyph itself which often is smaller, cf. figure 39 in section 9.2.4 in ISO 32000-1.

Comment: @David BTW, *just to support basic rendering/lend a helping hand to "dumb readers"* - nonetheless all PDF renderers have to use these values because there sometimes are weird PDFs which deliberately use wrong widths but compensate by additional offset (using TJ operators in a character-by-character manner), and the renderers are expected to properly render such PDF, too.